# Convert Lead to Patient - when click Cancel or Ok get error message

Tags: lightning-web-components, lead-conversion, health-cloud

Went through all setup recommendations fo Health Cloud:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_planning.htm

Created and customized  new apps: Health Cloud - Lightning Console, Health Cloud - Lightning Admin.

When we push button Cancel or OK in the end of converts, there is an error:

*This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: HealthCloudGA:wizard$controller$onCancelClicked [sforce is not defined] Failing descriptor: {HealthCloudGA:wizard$controller$onCancelClicked}*

Screenshots are attached.

Looks like a closing windows error .

Interestingly, the error is the same in the org from Trailhead and in the devsendbox from the Prod
[image: Error when Cancel clicked]
[image: Error in the end of conversation when Ok clicked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged further and found that this issue can be solved by disabling the LWS.

Session Settings -> Lightning Web Security - Disable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are closing the component you might be using

```
sforce.one.navigateToSobject(Id);
```

which is applicable only for VF Page on Mobile Apps

instead of using that , please use Aura Navigation

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            if(navEvt){
                navEvt.setParams({
                    "recordId": component.get("v.documentId") ,
                    "slideDevName": "detail"
                });
                navEvt.fire();
            }
```

If you are using LWC then use `NavigateMixin`

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: {yourSobjectID},
                objectApiName: {yourSObject},
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, that's good point. But it's Health Cloud manage package )

Comment: Then you may need to raise a case with SF Support to get this issue fixed.